# Create Simple Xaml Target Board

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to come up with simple target board, basically a circle with two perpendicular lines in xaml.  I have create an eclipse but I'm not sure how to draw the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Microsoft Expression (Blend and or Design) You can create vector paths which you can interact with programatically quite easily.

Other than that here is a reference on creating a line object:
http://www.longhorncorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/XamlLine06102005083411AM/XamlLine.aspx

Comment: I do not have blend or design.  I tried creating a line object and overlapped the ellipse, but it seems the fill color is always on top so my line is cut off.

Comment: That was fixed by changing the order in xaml.